# How to create a public database in hive beeline?

Tags: database, hive, beeline

Now I can use beeline to create `role` and `user`, every `user` have his/her own database using `admin` role to grant, but I need to create a new database that all users can create tables in the public database, how to create database like that?

Users can not create tables in other databases and can only create tables under their own databases.

Comment: Hello M.mary! Welcome to Stack Overflow! For tips on writing great questions visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you have any questions about the site, you can visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) or visit [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You need an *authorization provider* that supports Hive. [Apache Sentry](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_sg_sentry_service.html) is a popular one.

1. You will need to create a Sentry role that allows access to certain databases only.
2. Then assign a (Linux) group to that role.
3. Any user in above group will get access privileges to certain databases only (because of step 1.)